# Software that helps identify musical instruments and multiplicity in sound tracks

Tags: music, productivity, accessibility, music-production, music-recognition

The [Shazam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shazam.android) app can listen to sound and identify songs.

However, I am looking for an app (Android, iPhone, PC, Mac, Linux) that can listen to music (such as background music in cartoons and films), and output a graphical list of instruments with pictures, portraying the musical instruments that are used to produce the sound track or melody.

Ideally, the app should also output the guessed multiplicity for each instrument. This allows the user to gain an idea of number of instruments/players, involved.

This, among other things, would help user determine which instruments they liked and would like to like learning (based on which sounds they liked (the most).

Is there any app out there that manages to do all of this?

Thanks.